# We now have RunKeeper's Healthy Button on our site - use it!

Tags: discussion

I’m excited to announce that Fitness.SE is among RunKeeper‘s initial launch partners for the release of their new Healthy Button! Much like the buttons that allow you to share a post on Facebook, Twitter, or Google Plus, the RunKeeper Healthy Button allows you to share “fitness tips, inspiring stories and healthy food recipes” with your RunKeeper friends (your “street teammates”).

Here’s what it looks like on our site:

[image: RunKeeper location]

For those of you who haven’t used RunKeeper, it’s a really cool smart phone app that helps you track your workouts using GPS. It eliminates the need to plan out the route for your runs and bike rides – you can just go and RunKeeper will give you updates on distance, average speed, and calories burned. Everyone who signs up for RunKeeper also has a profile page that showcases your workouts. You can connect with your friends to see what they’ve been up to, comment, and help motivate each other. With the addition of the healthy button, you’ll now be able to share posts relating to healthy living with your friends as well!

So what does this mean for us? Basically, it’s a great new way for us to share Fitness.SE content with our RunKeeper friends. Sharing to Facebook, Twitter and Google Plus are all great for getting the word out to a really large network, but the RunKeeper network is more targeted towards people who are looking specifically for content like what we have – tips about exercise, nutrition, and healthy living. So every time you read a great post on fitness.stackexchange.com, hit that Healthy Button and share it with your RunKeeper friends!

Comment: I found a [bug](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/252/runkeeper-button-mashed-next-to-twitter-text).

Comment: Uh-oh! What's wrong with it?

Comment: It was something with some mismatched text and the button when you post a new answer. Jarrod already fixed it. :)