# RunKeeper Healthy button for the Fitness blog?

Tags: feature-request, blog

Since we have a [RunKeeper Healthy button](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/we-now-have-runkeepers-healthy-button-on-our-site-use-it) on the Fitness Stack Exchange site, I thought to myself, "Why not have the button on the [Fitness blog](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/) too?"

I managed to put some time aside and wrote a small, WordPress plugin. It displays the button at the top of a single WordPress post (but not on archives, index, etc. nor on pages; changing that though should be relatively trivial). **What does everyone think of putting this button on the Fitness blog?**

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like on my personal blog:
[image: RunKeeper Healthy button on my blog]

If you're interested in the code, it's available on GitHub: http://git.io/D6kj3A

**Update:** The plugin has been approved and is now listed on Wordpress.org.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-runkeeper-button/

Comment: I also pinged Rebecca Chernoff in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3803273#3803273) about this. I've requested to have it hosted on WordPress.org Plugins area. Hopefully I'll get an approval soon.

Comment: For any issues or suggestions, feel free to ping me on chat and also leave an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mattchan/wp_runkeeper_button).