# Pull the RunKeeper share button?

Tags: discussion

A little more than a month ago we [added a RunKeeper "healthy" button](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/we-now-have-runkeepers-healthy-button-on-our-site-use-it) to Fitness.SE posts as an experiment.  We were interested in seeing if targeted social sharing would pay better growth dividends than more general ones like Twitter and Facebook.

Well... it hasn't.  Looks like it's pulled in all of 0 hits and (maybe) 2 shares in the last week.  For comparison, Twitter's pulled in a minimum of few dozen people and Facebook's pulled in a dozen or so (it's harder to directly measure Twitter referrals due to all the clients, Facebook is pretty easy).

Since Fitness is due to get the [new beta theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/), and we'd have to convert the Run Keeper resources to it, now's the best time to decide whether or not to keep it.

So, **given how ineffective the Run Keeper sharing has been** is there a good reason to keep it?

<s>Lacking a compelling argument for it, we'll be pulling it in the next day or two.</s>

Yeah... we're pulling it in the beta theme conversion.  Stay tuned!

Answer (score 2):

I rarely use it, because I don't have a lot of friends on Runkeeper and those that I have are already members, which also follow me on Twitter. So in my specific echo chamber, there's too much redundancy for it to be useful.

But if nobody is using it, then clearly its not much use and we should probably look for other ways to partner with Runkeeper.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Ivo here.

Comment: I'm the same way... I have 0 people I know who use RunKeeper. I think it might be a valuable addition in the future as more people join the site that might be more involved on RunKeeper, but for now it is just using up space on the page.

Comment: Agree - I don't know anyone on RunKeeper, in fact had never heard of it before this button appeared.

Comment: What's the motivation for partnering with RunKeeper?

Comment: @Sancho a vain hope that it'll help us attract more runners?